# Getting OutOfBoundsException while using args array

Tags: java

I'm working on an assignment and I'm not allowed to use Scanner. Instead we have to use  `int money = Integer.parseInt(args[0])`. I tried writing my code and it compiles but there is a run time error and I was wondering if someone could tell me what I'm doing wrong to get me on the right track!

Here's my code:

```
class MakingChange {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int money   = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    int toonies = (money / 200);
    System.out.println(toonies);
  }
}
```

And the error is

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
at Money.main(Money.java:16)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at edu.rice.cs.drjava.model.compiler.JavacCompiler.runCommand(JavacCompiler.java:272)
```

I don't know what to make of this error! Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Run the program with an argument?

Answer (score 3):

You should write defensive code, try this:

```
if(args.length>0){
    int money   = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    int toonies = (money / 200);
    System.out.println(toonies);
}else{
    System.out.println("Missing Command Line Arguments");
}
```

Comment: It printed "Missing Command Line Arguments". What do i have to add to fix this problem, as i just want a random number to be given to me for this assignment?

Comment: you have to run your program from command  prompt and provide command line arguments. follow this link: http://www.javatpoint.com/command-line-argument

Comment: ya that's what i ended up doing thank you

Answer (score 2):

The problem is here:

```
int money = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
```

You are probably trying to access the first element of the args array,
but the array used is empty (zero items).

Are you sure you are passing any parameters correctly to your application?
They should be space separated with the program, while executing your compiled program (here is an example using jar file):

```
java -jar MyProgram.jar 1234
```

You could add some error handling code in order to prevent this, such as an if statement checking the args array size:

```
int money = 0;
if(array.size() != 0) {
    money = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
}
```

Or even by using a try-catch block:

```
try {
    //....
    int money = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    //....
}
catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
    //Error handling code here.
    System.err.println(e.getMessage());
}
```

Comment: I thought the array is supposed to be 0, that way I would be able to generate a random number. Also, when I tried checking the array size, Dr. Java told me there is no variable named array and it could not find the symbol. I'm sorry if the answers to these are obvious but I'm fairly new to programming and I'm at a loss here.

Comment: Well, `args` is a Java array, containing the command line arguments (notice that `main()` takes it as argument) passed to your program when executed. `args[0]` means "the first `args` array element" (in arrays, counting starts from 0, therefore `args[0]` is for the 1st array element, `args[1]` for the second etc).

Comment: So then what do I do to fix the error?

Comment: Please read my answer in detail. Thanks.

Comment: Well, if you're suggesting I change args[0] to args[1] it made no difference.

Comment: Well, this is not my suggestion. What you must do, is execute your program and pass the value you want as first argument, in order for the `args` to contain an element. Also, you can add an if statement or an exception handling to prevent it from crashing if no argument is passed. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You are not passing any arguments to your program.

Add this at the start of your method:

```
if (args.length == 0)
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("No arguments found");
```

To pass arguments, do this:

```
java Money 123
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` means that you are trying to access an index in memory that is not used or initialized.

It looks like you are running your program via the command line; you need to pass arguments to your compiled `.class` file to get this to even run.